# Which Calendar ID to use in Google Calendar API?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I currently retrieve my organization (family) Google Calendars via the Google Calendar API, using Python.

For reference, the credentials file used in both cases is (`(...)` is redacted information)

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "da(...)",
  "private_key_id": "8(...)4",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAI(...)Kag==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "da(...)@(...).iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "1(...)9",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/da(...)iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I would like to port this to Go. To do so, I used the following code (partly copied from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/go))

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

    "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func googlecalendar() (err error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    calendarService, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("googlecalendar.json"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
    events, err := calendarService.Events.List("john@example.com").ShowDeleted(false).
        SingleEvents(true).TimeMin(t).MaxResults(10).OrderBy("startTime").Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve next ten of the user's events: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Upcoming events:")
    if len(events.Items) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No upcoming events found.")
    } else {
        for _, item := range events.Items {
            date := item.Start.DateTime
            if date == "" {
                date = item.Start.Date
            }
            fmt.Printf("%v (%v)\n", item.Summary, date)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the code above `john@example.com` is the "Calendar ID" provided in Google Calendar (the actual ID is used in the code of course). This outputs the error

```
time="2021-05-05T11:39:12+02:00" level=fatal msg="Unable to retrieve next ten of the user's events: googleapi: Error 404: Not Found, notFound"
```

**My understanding is that this means that `john@example.com` was not recognized. Why?**

When instead of `john@example.com` I use `primary` (as in the docs), the code runs correctly and outputs

```
Upcoming events:
No upcoming events found.
```

This means that **the whole authentication part seems to work** (using the same JSON credentials as in Python, retrieved from the console) - it is just that the reference to the calendar is not correct. How to fix this?

---

Following a request in comments, below is the general Python code (that works).

```
import json
import logging.config
import os

import arrow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import paho.mqtt.publish
from google.oauth2 import service_account as google_oauth2_service_account


# setup logging
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': "%(asctime)s [%(module)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # root logger
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': logging.ERROR,
            'propagate': False
        },
        'googlecalendar': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG if os.environ.get('DEBUG', '').lower() == 'true' else logging.INFO,
            'propagate': False
        },
    },
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "version": 1,
})
log = logging.getLogger('googlecalendar')


def getevents(calendar=None, google_service =None):
    now = arrow.now()
    try:
        events_result = google_service.events().list(
            calendarId=calendar,
            timeMin=now.shift(days=0).isoformat(),
            timeMax=now.shift(days=+7).isoformat(),
            singleEvents=True,
            orderBy='startTime'
        ).execute()
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"error connecting to google for {calendar}: {e}")
        return

    # transform events and send out
    events = []
    if events_result.get('items'):
        # remove multiday items (no strat or end date)
        for i in events_result['items']:
            # try to extract the data, some are not available so the event is not interesing (multiday, ...)
            try:
                events.append({
                    'start': arrow.get(i['start']['dateTime']).isoformat(),
                    'end': arrow.get(i['end']['dateTime']).isoformat(),
                    'timestamp': arrow.get(i['start']['dateTime']).timestamp,
                    'name': i['summary'],
                    'id': i['id'],
                    'important': True if i.get('colorId') else False
                })
            except KeyError:
                pass

    # send the data to MQTT
    # (...)

    log.debug(f"{calendar}: {events}")


google_credentials = google_oauth2_service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "da(...)",
      "private_key_id": "8(...)4",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAI(...)Kag==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "da(...)@(...).iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "1(...)9",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/da(...)iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    subject='john@example.com'
)
google_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=google_credentials, cache_discovery=False)

for calendar in [
    "john@example.com",
    "mary@example.net",
    "something_idsd@group.calendar.google.com",
]:
    getevents(calendar=calendar, google_service=google_service)
```

Comment: Did you enable the service account domain wide dedication in in your Google workspace account?

Comment: I think you forgot to add config.Subject = userEmail on your client.

Comment: @DaImTo: *Did you enable the service account domain wide dedication in in your Google workspace account?* → yes I did

Comment: @DaImTo: *I think you forgot to add config.Subject = userEmail on your client* → where should I add that? (which config?)

Comment: Have a look at this example just remember your using the calendar id and not the domain admin api   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#go

Comment: Could you show the Python code that works correctly?

Comment: I thought you wanted it working in GO   [delegation sample with python](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#python)  unfortunately google doesn't create samples for everything for ever API in every language.  You kind of have to pick it up from different APIs and work it out :)

Comment: @DaImTo: yes, I wanted to make it work in Go - I mentioned the Python aspect so that we start from a baseline ("it works in Python so all the prereqs are in place" vs "how to access the API" :))

Comment: @fullfine: sure, I added it at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

The result you are getting is normal, the problem is that you are not performing [Domain-Wide Delegation correctly](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#go). I come to this conclusion because of the following scenarios:

1. Calendar Id: `john@example.com`. If the service account has not impressed the user, it is expected that the user's calendar will not be found.
2. Calendar Id: `primary`. If the primary calendar of the service account does not have any events, it is expected that the `list` method does not return any results.

## Solution

Comparing your code with the one in the documentation, I don't see where you place `config.Subject = userEmail`, as @DalmTo says. Try the [following code](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#go) to create the calendar service:

```
  ctx := context.Background()

  jsonCredentials, err := ioutil.ReadFile("googlecalendar.json")
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonCredentials, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
  if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("JWTConfigFromJSON: %v", err)
  }
  config.Subject = "john@example.com"

  ts := config.TokenSource(ctx)

  calendarService, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(ts))
```

## References:

- [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#go)

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I modified your code to account for the correct scope.